# Migrating SBS 2011 "Data Drive" to NAS iSCSI

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, migration, network-attached-storage, windows-sbs-2011

Our business has a Windows SBS 2011 server with two volumes mounted, C:\ and D:\, it is our only server and ADDC.

D:\ holds all of our shared folders which are simple folders with access rights determined by user groups created in SBS Console. We aren't using Sharepoint or DFS.

So if we want to mount our IT folder, it is located at D:\Department\IT and that's as complex as it gets.

What we want to do is migrate all of this data over to a QNAP NAS unit. I have successfully mounted an iSCSI volume and it is currently assigned as E:\

It has been suggested that we could simply use Robocopy to mirror the data on D:\ to E:\ ensuring that we copy permissions and then simply swap the drive letters and nobody would notice anything different.

As a 24/7 company with few opportunities for downtime, we're struggling to come up with a bullet proof solution to migrate seamlessly and the above is the best we can come up with but we're nervous about it...it seems too simple.

Could anyone confirm if this would work and if not, what are some other methods we could implement to migrate as smoothly as possible?

Comment: Without being overly negative, this sounds like a terrible idea.  Putting your SBS shares on iSCSI on QNAP is not going to be a 'bulletproof' solution for a '24/7 company'.  Doing so with a dearth of technical knowledge / experience is worse.  I wouldn't.

Comment: I agree, however it's a short term solution to an ageing server managed by an awful 3rd party who want to charge the earth for very small storage upgrades. We will eventually move to a cloud based solution but budgets are very tight at the moment and we have 12TB of unused storage on a brand new NAS just sitting waiting meanwhile our server is at a critical point with data storage. We don't need the bad idea to be bullet proof, we need the execution of the bad idea to be bullet proof.

Comment: I will test when I have time, but I would unshare and recreate the shares from the new location rather than trying to switch drive letters and keep the existing shares.  That is guaranteed to work, it's a standard approach for migrating shares.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare yourself a short maintenance window and try it. If the test user doesn't loose folder permissions and can continue working with the share without issues, the chances are high other users can do so as well.

Anyways, you would still be able to roll-back everything with no efforts.

And I agree with @BlueCompute that spawning an iSCSI target on a standalone QNAP is not the best idea for a 24/7 company.